# What's the correct way to upload a HTML package to MailChimp?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mailchimp

MailChimp is stripping out a DIV inside an anchor whenever I upload a ZIP with all the contents of my campaign, and of course it messes up the design of the email and sizes.

code snippet:

```
<td style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
    <a href=#" target="_blank">
    <div class="img-thumb" style="margin:0 auto">
        <img src="./thumbnail_video_naba.png"></img>
    </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried without the div? What does the class `img-thumb` do in the code?

Comment: I always copy and paste. It's much safer. Something weird happens when you upload.